# Ubuntu 20.04 - "python-reportlab" not possible to install - Print driver with advaced features not installable

Tags: python, printing, 20.04

I try to install an advanced print-driver for Kyocera TASKalfa 3252ci.

The Problem is that `python-reportlab` is not installable for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

---

There is only python3-reportlab but this is not working with that print-driver.

Also `python-is-python2` and `python-is-python3` are not working.

---

Is there a possibility to fix this problem?

Terminal:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i kyodialog_5.0-0_amd64.deb 

(Reading database ... 275586 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kyodialog_5.0-0_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kyodialog (5.0-0) over (5.0-0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kyodialog:
 kyodialog depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.
 kyodialog depends on python-reportlab; however:
  Package python-reportlab is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package kyodialog (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kyodialog
```

Comment: If your driver won't work with python3-reportlab then you could look for newer driver. Failing that you could install  `python-is-python2`, then get these 2 packages, https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan-updates/python-reportlab & https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan-updates/python-reportlab-accel  Then install both together with apt. Ex. -  `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/python-reportlab_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb  ~/Downloads/python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb`  Or go back to 18.04..

Comment: Many thanks.
It worked to install python-reportlab on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

Many thanks. Solved the problem.

`sudo apt-get install python-is-python2`

Download [python-reportlab](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan-updates/python-reportlab) & [python-reportlab-accel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan-updates/python-reportlab-accel)

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb

wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-reportlab/python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./python-reportlab_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb ./python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb
```

Now it was possible to install the driver.

Comment: I tried to download python-reportlab_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_all.deb and python-reportlab-accel_3.5.23-1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb but under the given links the files are not to be found

Comment: Files are available here:

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/18623432

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was mistakenly running `dpkg -i` instead of `apt install` on the downloaded debs. Does anybody know the difference ?